# Software for auto parts management

Tags: windows, database, data

My name is Adrian.
We own a second hand car parts store. We buy cars, disassemble them, and sell them by the piece.
At the current moment all the prices are, unfortunately, in my head, so we need to catalog them in some way.
I need a platform where I can organize this data, so it will be easy for other employees to find a specific car part with their specific price and details.

For example, I just disassembled a Hyundai Accent 2008 1.5 CRDi.
I need to be able to create several categories as follows:

Manufacturer - Model - Production interval - Body style - Engine Engine type / Engine power

Hyundai - Accent - 2005 2011 - 4 door sedan - 1.5 CRDi - D4FA / 112cp

A specific set of parts will be added for this entry; I need to preset specific sets of items for each variation of the vehicle.

In addition, Kia Rio 2005 - 2011 is the equivalent of Hyundai Accent 2005 - 2011, 80% of the parts are the same.
It will go in different categories, but the two must be connected in some way, if i do changes to one auto part (Rio) I need to control whether it affects both entries (Rio and Accent) or just the one I’m currently working on (Rio).

Looking from the pricing point of view, there are several classes:

- Class A - the lowest value ($)
- Class B - ($$)
- Class C - ($$$)
  Etc.
  When adding a new vehicle, this attribute needs to be set so that the prices will apply automatically for all the parts that the entry generates, afterwards the price list will be fine tuned.

Using a different approach, it can be relatively easy to implement:

- Level 1 - Pricing Class (will define the price for all the parts)
- Level 2 - Manufacturer
- Level 3 - Car model (at this point the standard set of items will be added)
- Level 4 - Production interval
- Level 5 - Body style

  - a) 4 door sedan (4 door sedan car parts will be added)
  - b) 2 door hatchback (2 door hatchback car parts will be added)
  - c) etc
- Level 6 - Engine

  - a) diesel engine

    - i. classic diesel engine (classic diesel engine part package added)
    - ii. common rail diesel engine
    - iii. etc
  - b) gasoline engine
- Level 7 - Engine type, Engine Power
- Level 8 - Additional options (checklist of some sort)

  - a) AC (will add several items)
  - b) ABS (will add several items)
  - c) ESP (will add several items)
  - d) etc.

I need to be able to predefine specific sets of items for each variation.

Our first top priority is to index all the cars so that we have a flexible, easy to find price list, where employees can add, delete, change data, input pictures or notes. Eventually it will be used as an inventory program. Maybe in the future, an online shop.

I think I covered all the important aspects of the program, with all the platforms out there I’m sure all of this can be accomplished in multiple and easier ways, so please share whatever knowledge you think will help.
Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, Adrian.  Is there a particular operating system you have in mind?  What about cost?

Comment: Windows / Browser based platform, monthly or yearly fees accepted, thanks!

Comment: @zloteaadrian, please can you confirm how you resolved this. Thanks.